# PyMongo - Aggregation pipeline to get user - mentioned user network

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have uploaded some tweets in a Mongo DB collection and I would like to extract the following information with PyMongo:

- user.screen_name
- entities.user_mentions.screen_name
- count

i.e. I would like to know who has mentioned whom and how many times, in order to create some kind of network.

I used the following pipeline to get the most mentioned users but I'm not able to introduce also the user.screen_name:

```
tweets.aggregate([
    {'$project': {'mentions': '$entities.user_mentions.screen_name', '_id': 0}},
    {'$unwind': '$mentions'},
    {'$group': {'_id': '$mentions', 'count': {'$sum': 1}}}
])
```

Here an example of document (tweet), where I removed some of the fields I'm not interested in:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('604c805b289d1ef5947e1845'),
 'created_at': 'Fri Mar 12 04:36:10 +0000 2021',
 'display_text_range': [0, 140],
 'entities': {'hashtags': [{'indices': [124, 136], 'text': 'mytag'}],
              'symbols': [],
              'urls': [],
              'user_mentions': [{'id': 123,
                                 'id_str': '123',
                                 'indices': [3, 14],
                                 'name': 'user_name',
                                 'screen_name': 'user_screen_name'}]},
 'user': {'id': 456,
          'id_str': '456',
          'name': 'Author Name',
          'screen_name': 'Author Screen Name'}}

{'_id': ObjectId('604c805b289d1ef5947e184x'),
 'created_at': 'Fri Mar 12 04:36:10 +0000 2021',
 'display_text_range': [0, 140],
 'entities': {'hashtags': [{'indices': [124, 136], 'text': 'mytag'}],
              'symbols': [],
              'urls': [],
              'user_mentions': [{'id': 126,
                                 'id_str': '126',
                                 'indices': [3, 14],
                                 'name': 'user_name',
                                 'screen_name': 'user_screen_name'}]},
 'user': {'id': 4567,
          'id_str': '4567',
          'name': 'Other Author Name',
          'screen_name': 'Other Author Screen Name'}}
```

In this example I would expect something like:

```
{'mentioned': 'user_screen_name',
'author': 'Author Screen Name',
'count': '1'},
{'mentioned': 'user_screen_name',
'author': 'Other Author Screen Name',
'count': '1'},
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Francesca

Comment: can you post your sample documents?

Comment: Thank you @varman for the suggestion. I added a piece of document hoping it can clarify

Comment: Hope this https://mongoplayground.net/p/xoDJfX1TsxU u need?

Comment: @varman not exactly, this returns me only the user being mentioned (in my example it was user_screen_name), and not the author of the tweet (in my example it was Author Name)

Comment: Ok, can you remove unwanted fields and show us what is the expected output

Comment: I added my expected result! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "mentions": "$entities.user_mentions.screen_name",
      "author": "$user.screen_name"
    }
  },
  { "$unwind": "$mentions" },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": { aut: "$author", ment: "$mentions" },
      "count": { "$sum": 1 },
      author: { "$first": "$author" },
      mentions: { "$first": "$mentions" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": { _id: 0 }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qE1tqBzjm_y)**

Comment: Thank you for the solution. However in this way I only get the first author who mentioned the mentioned user, while I would like to get all possible pairs author-mentioned.. is there a way to do this?

Comment: So you need to show us, how do u need and how your document is

Comment: done again :) sorry for not being clear at the very beginning :(